# The site cannot be reached in Apache Tomcat WebServer

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have downloaded eclipse and tomcat. I tried to create a server in Eclipse. I do not have any project at this point.

It starts, It's HTTP port number is 8080.

But when I try to access it from browser. It does not work . It says the site cannot be reached.

I tried to access through
localhost:8080

**I ran netstat -na**

**Output**

Active Connections

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:33060          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49669          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:63937          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1001         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8254         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8254         127.0.0.1:56628        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8254         127.0.0.1:56695        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19612        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19612        127.0.0.1:55755        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49677        127.0.0.1:49678        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49678        127.0.0.1:49677        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49681        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49681        127.0.0.1:57503        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55744        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55755        127.0.0.1:19612        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55756        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:56628        127.0.0.1:8254         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:56695        127.0.0.1:8254         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57503        127.0.0.1:49681        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:139        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.0.4:49228      34.194.96.239:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:49249      216.239.32.116:443     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50939      172.217.167.195:443    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50962      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50965      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50966      10.254.254.112:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50969      10.254.254.116:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50970      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50972      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50973      10.254.254.113:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50974      10.254.254.129:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50975      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50979      10.254.254.128:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50981      10.254.254.112:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50982      10.254.254.113:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50983      10.254.254.114:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50989      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50993      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50997      10.254.254.129:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50998      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:50999      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51002      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51010      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51016      10.254.254.115:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51017      10.254.254.116:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51019      10.254.254.117:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51020      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51023      10.254.254.119:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51027      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51029      10.254.254.127:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51031      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51032      10.254.254.125:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51033      4.16.74.104:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51035      10.254.254.117:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51040      10.254.254.122:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51042      10.254.254.115:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51047      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51050      10.254.254.128:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51051      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51052      10.254.254.112:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51055      10.254.254.114:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51062      10.254.254.115:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51064      103.124.96.149:47464   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51067      10.254.254.121:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51069      10.254.254.116:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51070      10.254.254.113:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51072      10.254.254.113:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51073      10.254.254.116:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51075      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51076      10.254.254.115:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51077      10.254.254.126:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51080      52.206.44.147:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51081      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51086      172.217.166.202:443    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51087      172.217.31.2:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51088      172.217.31.2:443       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51089      192.0.73.2:443         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51091      198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51092      99.86.47.24:443        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51093      10.254.254.117:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51094      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51095      10.254.254.114:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51097      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51104      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51105      203.86.196.1:34156     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51108      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51111      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51112      103.124.96.171:47464   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51117      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51118      10.254.254.117:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51119      10.254.254.111:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51122      10.254.254.118:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51124      10.254.254.116:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51125      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51127      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51130      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51131      52.114.32.8:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51132      10.254.254.119:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51133      10.254.254.114:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51135      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51137      10.254.254.128:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51138      10.254.254.111:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51139      10.254.254.117:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51140      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51141      10.254.254.121:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51143      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51145      10.254.254.112:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51147      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51150      103.103.8.170:63414    FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51152      10.254.254.118:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51154      94.227.161.30:18922    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51155      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51156      4.16.74.136:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51157      10.254.254.123:55501   SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51158      177.17.35.49:6881      SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51159      103.214.202.13:8999    SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51162      4.16.72.100:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51163      10.254.254.114:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51164      10.254.254.113:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51165      10.254.254.125:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51166      103.103.8.167:63414    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51167      4.16.72.100:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51168      24.163.66.84:6881      SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51169      10.254.254.123:55501   SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51170      41.242.78.19:32604     SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51171      4.16.72.100:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51172      4.16.72.100:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51175      10.254.254.115:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51176      4.16.72.100:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51178      4.16.72.100:443        TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51179      10.254.254.113:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51180      10.254.254.122:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51181      10.254.254.112:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51182      10.254.254.128:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51183      4.16.72.100:443        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:51185      10.254.254.119:55501   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63381      74.125.24.188:5228     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63764      40.119.211.203:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63937      39.38.55.225:53303     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63937      39.38.55.225:53339     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63937      182.48.66.41:49604     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63937      182.48.66.41:50430     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63937      182.48.66.41:65163     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63937      188.146.41.118:53142   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63937      213.118.12.106:56780   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:63937      221.121.133.118:62615  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:64698      172.217.166.14:443     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:64900      151.101.129.69:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:64902      151.101.129.69:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.0.4:64915      99.86.47.2:443         TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.0.4:65185      172.217.167.35:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:7680              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:33060             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49664             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49665             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49666             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49667             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49668             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49669             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:63937             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  UDP    0.0.0.0:67             *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1900           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5050           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:63937          *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:6771         *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49664        *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59439        *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59880        *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.0.4:137        *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.0.4:138        *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.0.4:1900       *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.0.4:6771       *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.0.4:59438      *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.0.4:59879      *:*                    
  UDP    [::]:500               *:*                    
  UDP    [::]:4500              *:*                    
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*                    
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*                    
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                    
  UDP    [::]:63937             *:*                    
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                    
  UDP    [::1]:59437            *:*                    
  UDP    [fe80::8a:a9d2:b31d:afe7%5]:1900  *:*                    
  UDP    [fe80::8a:a9d2:b31d:afe7%5]:59436  *:*
```

The weird thing is when start Apache Tomcat from Window+r>Services.msc>Apache Tomcat>start. It starts.and I can access it from localhost:8080

**Server Log From Eclipse Console tab**

```
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.53
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 11 2020 10:01:39 UTC
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 8.5.53.0
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_241-b07
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\WAHEGURU\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\WAHEGURU\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\WAHEGURU\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin;E:\softwares\ffmpeg-20200330-8d019db-win64-static\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\WAHEGURU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\WAHEGURU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Users\WAHEGURU\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;E:\softwares\eclipse;;.]
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:42 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1025 ms
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.53
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 04, 2020 5:39:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 382 ms
```

Comment: How do you try accessing it. First start the server. Then go to your browser and type <IP address>:<port> that's all

Comment: that is exactly what I did.@D. Sikilai

Comment: Then can you post a sample of your code with confidential details omitted.

Comment: also, some server logs would be helpful

Comment: I do not have any project. It have just downloaded eclipse and tomcat. Installed them. tried to create a server. @D. Sikilai

Comment: @Karthikeyan How can I post my server logs?

Comment: Try to see with the command line tool: `netstat -na` whether Tomcat is listening on that port, depending on your operating system and privileges you can add extra options to see which sockets belong to which process identifier.

Comment: I have added my netstat -na output in my post @JohannesB

Comment: As you can see from netstat there is no server process listening on port 8080, so either it is not running (anymore) or listening on a different port. As you seem to use Windows you can also use: `netstat -naop TCP |findstr LISTENING` to see in the last column which process it is and compare with e.g. the process ID's in Taskmanager or: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: The weired thing is when start Apache Tomcat from Services.msc. It starts.and I can access it from localhost:8080 @JohannesB

Comment: You still didn't show any logging from Tomcat which should be visible from the Console window in Eclipse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210932/discussion-between-aman-and-johannesb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using

Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)

Apache Tomcat version: 8.5

start Eclipse>
create a server
Do as this:

Eclipse >toolbar>Windows -> Show View -> Servers

Then in the Servers view, right-click and add new. It will show a pop up containing many server vendors. Under Apache select Tomcat v7.0 (Depending upon your downloaded server version). And in the run time configuration point it to the Tomcat folder you have downloaded.

> Click on server settings

[image]

Now

[image]

> start server

Right click on newly created server
select start

Try to access

localhost:8080

on your favourite browser.

Although, I have no idea why this worked. I saw this solution in a youtube. I tried it. And It worked. I posted it here.So if someone faces the same problem. It will help them. I hope.
If anyone can provide some better explanation than me. feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Although, I have no idea why this worked. I saw this solution in a youtube. I tried it. And It worked. I posted it here.So if someone faces the same problem. It will help them. I hope.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the console output from the server to get a clue of what goes wrong when you try to start it:

[image: Tomcat running from Eclipse]

It may reveal whether you have a configuration or permissions error etc.